# File is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, installation, compatibility

I have a really old installer (legacy app) that we are trying to get running on a Windows 7 64 bit os.

Previously it has only been installed on Windows XP 32 bit.  I get the following error when I try to run it:

```
The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows 
you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether 
you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then 
contact the software publisher.
```

Contacting the software publisher is not an option (software is super old).

Is there a way to get this to work?  Some sort of compatibility mode?

The only thing I have heard of that will work is a Virtual XP on the Win 7 box.  The problem is that this software is a part of a whole software set.  I would have to put all of the pieces on the Virtual XP or none at all.

Before I go down the road of putting it all on the virtual xp I would like to know that there is no way to get it all on the Win 7 os.

Comment: What program is it? What does it do? Does it include a driver install or control specialized hardware? I know that legacy software for devices like old CNC Mills don't really work on win7.

Comment: @Doltknuckle - It is an installer that has the 1999(ish) Delphi BDE in it.  We need the BDE to run other legacy apps.  There are no drivers in the installer.

Comment: Does the file name end in .com?

Comment: No, it is an installer built with install shield.  It ends in exe.

Comment: I managed to get this exact same error on a 64 bit machine by accidentally renaming a zip file to an exe.
This is not an answer by itself I know, but is something that I couldn't find by googling.

Answer (score 7):

You say it is a really old installer, is it a 16-bit application? All 16-bit application support was dropped from Windows 7 x64 - It will not run, at all. You will need to use an emulator or move back to 32-bit Windows. XP mode in Windows 7 might be an easy solution to get this application up and running seamlessly.

Comment: I don't know if it is 16 bit.  I don't think so, but how can I find out the "bit" status of my installer?  (Just to be sure.)

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/security/learnmore/spot16bit.mspx Shows how to detect a 16-bit application, but you might need to have a working copy of Windows XP.

Comment: Yep, that message indicates that you are trying to run a 16-bit application on a 64-bit machine. HOWEVER, 16-bit support was NOT dropped in Windows 7 like the answer says, but actually is not permitted (i.e. will refuse to execute) by the CPU itself if it is running in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @Hello71 Yes, and just as it switches to 32-bit mode for SysWoW, I suppose it could be further switched. With regards to the 64-bit kernel for Vista and Windows 7: "However, the kernel does not support 16-bit applications, 32-bit installers, and 32-bit kernel mode drivers."

Comment: Actually, IIRC, the CPU will not execute 16-bit code in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @Hello is right, an x86-64 CPU running Windows in "full" 64-bit mode will not run 16 bit code: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282423  Also in full 64-bit mode a number of 16-bit CPU features are disabled as per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64 (see "Removal of older features")

Answer (score 3):

With legacy installers you really just have to fiddle around with the settings.  Try setting compatibility mode to Windows XP SP 3 and Set run as administrator.

Some legacy installers can be "unzipped".  Meaning some zip utilities can actually unzip the files the program is supposed to install.  Now I don't recommend it, but you could try to manually move the files yourself.

Comment: Inside the .exe installer was the installer for GTA2.exe that worked. Thank you very much! (I've used Winrar). I'm afraid I would not have thought that, so, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If running the installer in compatibility mode with UAC turned off ([registry change](http://www.petri.co.il/disable-uac-in-windows-7.htm)) doesn't work, the next step is to try a manual install. This is where you use file comparison techniques to find what the installer actually does to your computer and mirroring that to your windows 7 machine. If you've never done this before, I wouldn't recommend it because you can run into a lot of problems trying to get everything working. Which I know from experience is a real pain to get everything.

The better option is to download and enable XP mode in windows 7 (doesn't work with win 7 home or starter). This would at least give you desktop shortcuts that launch the VM on demand. You can find it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I have had the exact same error message for a **corrupt** installer.

An installer that was created for Windows 7 (32bit/64bit) in the first place, got corrupt while being transferred via email, showing this message (on Windows 7 64bit). The non-corrupt file installed fine.

So, I suggest you try the installer on a Win XP machine before trying more technical operations.

If the installer is indeed corrupt, then you will have to find a backup or get it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also appear when you create a script and save it as *.exe instead of *.bat. Switching to *.bat can solve the problem.